# Php 5.3.3. Access log

Tags: php, php-fpm, php53

I'm using php-fpm.
In 5.3.2 when I'm opening phpinfo page in access log I get:

```
ip - - [26/Aug/2010:16:35:32 +0400] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 13322 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
```

But in 5.3.3 I'm getting:

```
ip - - [26/Aug/2010:16:30:30 +0400] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11891 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
ip - - [26/Aug/2010:16:30:30 +0400] "GET /phpinfo.php?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 HTTP/1.1" 200 2536 "http://site.com/phpinfo.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
ip - - [26/Aug/2010:16:30:30 +0400] "GET /phpinfo.php?=SUHO8567F54-D428-14d2-A769-00DA302A5F18 HTTP/1.1" 200 2825 "http://site.com/phpinfo.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
ip - - [26/Aug/2010:16:30:30 +0400] "GET /phpinfo.php?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 HTTP/1.1" 200 2158 "http://site.com/phpinfo.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
```

Why there is 4 lines insted of 1? And what means "?=PHPE...". Is it PHP sessions?

My php5.3.3 fpm config:

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
log_level = notice
[pool_0]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.backlog = -1
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 500
pm.status_path = /pool_0/status
rlimit_files = 1024
rlimit_core = 0
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_flag[register_globals] = true
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 15
php_admin_flag[short_open_tag] = true
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = false
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `expose_php` setting is switched on, the `phpinfo` output includes 3 logo images. These are loaded using the three extra requests you are seeing in your log file.